# what is difference between Array and ArrayList to get Prime numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i was solving problem about the prime numbers, i found solution using Arrays, but i wanted to use the array list for some issues, one of them is to understand the Arraylist  well. but i found that the results are not the same when i use the arraylist, here are the 2 Codes:

//using Arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primeNumber(100);
    }
    public static void primeNumber(int end) {
        boolean primeNumbers[] = new boolean[end]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            primeNumbers[i] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < primeNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (primeNumbers[i] ) {
                for (int j = i+i; j < primeNumbers.length; j += i) {
                    primeNumbers[j]= false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 2; j < primeNumbers.length; j++) {
            if (primeNumbers[j]) {
                System.out.println(j);

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

//Using ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primeNumber(100);
    }

    public static void primeNumber(int end) {
        ArrayList<Boolean> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            primeNumbers.add(i,true);
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < primeNumbers.size(); i++) {
            if (primeNumbers.get(i) ) {
                for (int j = i+i; j < primeNumbers.size(); j += i) {
                    primeNumbers.add(j, false);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 2; j < primeNumbers.size(); j++) {
            if (primeNumbers.get(j)) {
                System.out.println(j);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can i know what is the wrong i did with using the Arraylist, and if i wanted to use the arraylist for the same result what should i do.

Great thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't need `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
primeNumbers.add(j, false);
```

you should use

```
primeNumbers.set(j, false);
```

since [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) adds a new element at the specified position (meaning the ArrayList grows by one element), but [`set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) only sets the value of the element at specified position.

Answer (score 4):

```
primeNumbers.add(j, false);
```

**adds the element** to the array list, and shifting all elements with index >= `j` to the right [including the previous element `j`], while:

```
primeNumbers[j]= false
```

**overrides the existing element** `j`, and does not shift elements.

You are probably looking for [`ArrayList.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) instead of [`ArrayList.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 0):

Difference between **Array** and **ArrayList** are following:

1. Implementation of array is simple fixed sized array but Implementation of ArrayList is dynamic sized array.
2. Array can contain both primitives and objects but ArrayList can contain only object elements
3. You can’t use generics along with array but ArrayList allows us to use generics to ensure type safety.
4. You can use *length* variable to calculate length of an array but *size()*  method to calculate size of ArrayList.
5. Array use assignment operator to store elements but ArrayList use *add()* to insert elements.